# How to configure proxy server with wildfly-maven-plugin?

Tags: java, maven, jboss, proxy, wildfly

I have configured my WildFly 8.2.0 server to allow for remote deployment with the maven-wildfly-plugin. I have verified that this works from a computer not connected through a proxy server. However, when using a computer that is trying to connect through a forward proxy server, I get:

```
java.net.ConnectException: WFLYPRT0023: Could not connect to http-remoting://x.x.x.x:9990. The connection timed out
```

I have tried to look through the documentation and the code, but I can't find anything on this topic.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try configuring your proxy JVM-wide using system properties (http.proxyHost and http.proxyPort). You should probably configure those in the 'argLine' property in your Maven plugin configuration.

Answer (score -1):

Try to configure the proxy server in the settings.xml

https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html

Comment: From what I can tell, this will only configure maven requests to use the proxy, but not the requests that are made from within the plugins themselves. Can you verify this? I have tried setting it anyway, but I don't notice any difference.

Comment: You are right. Then try to set the proxy as java system properties http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html

Comment: I tried adding those to MAVEN_OPTS, but no difference. Does the wildfly-maven-plugin not have build-in support for proxy servers?

Comment: Does your proxy allow to connect to port 9990 anyway? Most proxy servers doesn't, so even when you configure your proxy server, the connection will time out.

Comment: When I use a browser, that is configured to use the proxy, I can log into the remote management console via port 9990.